# php create xml CDATA on loop

Tags: php, xml

want to make loop and Parsing XML CDATA 
my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<photos>
    <photo image="images/1.jpg" url="http://LINKHERE" target="_blank" id="1">
    </photo>
    <photo image="images/1.jpg" url="http://LINKHERE" target="_blank" id="2">
    </photo>
</photos>
```

my code

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    $dom=new DOMDocument();
    $xml='images.xml';
    $dom->load($xml);
    $xp = new DomXPath($dom);
    //$item_content = $xp->query("//*[@id = $x]");
    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('photos') as $item) {
        $cdata=$dom->createCDATASection('<head>test'.$x.'</head><body></body>');
        $item->getElementsByTagName('photo')->item(0)->appendChild($cdata);
    }
    $dom->save($xml);
}
```

but the result

```
    <photo image="images/1.jpg" url="http://LINKHERE" target="_blank" id="1">
    <![CDATA[<head>test1</head><body></body><head>test2</head><body></body><head>test3</head><body></body>
    <head>test4</head><body></body><head>test5</head><body></body>
<head>test6</head><body></body><head>test7</head>
    <body></body><head>test8</head><body></body><head>test9</head><body></body>]]><![CDATA[<head>test10</head><body>
    </body>]]></photo>
    <photo image="images/2.jpg" url="http://http://LINKHERE" target="_blank" id="2">
    </photo>
```

i want it be this

```
<photo image="images/1.jpg" url="http://LINKHERE" target="_blank" id="1">
<![CDATA[<head>test1</head><body></body>]]></photo>
<photo image="images/2.jpg" url="http://http://LINKHERE" target="_blank" id="2">
<![CDATA[<head>test2</head><body></body>]]></photo>
```

i want move on loop by id
i try many times but no way , i think i have a problem on my loop
need some help here

Answer (score 0):

You want to append CData on each `photo` element, so you should loop through `photo` instead of `photos`, for example :

```
$raw = <<<XML
<photos>
    <photo image="images/1.jpg" url="http://LINKHERE" target="_blank" id="1">
    </photo>
    <photo image="images/1.jpg" url="http://LINKHERE" target="_blank" id="2">
    </photo>
</photos>
XML;
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($raw);
$x = 1;
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('photo') as $item) {
    $cdata=$dom->createCDATASection('<head>test'.$x.'</head><body></body>');
    $item->appendChild($cdata);
    $x++;
}
echo $dom->saveXML($xml);
```

**<kbd>[`eval.in demo`](https://eval.in/573324)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<photos>
    <photo image="images/1.jpg" url="http://LINKHERE" target="_blank" id="1">
    <![CDATA[<head>test1</head><body></body>]]></photo>
    <photo image="images/1.jpg" url="http://LINKHERE" target="_blank" id="2">
    <![CDATA[<head>test2</head><body></body>]]></photo>
</photos>
```

Comment: thank u it work, just anther thing , if i want edit CDATA value from test1 to anther value it there  edirCDATASection or what? thank u  again

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php
    $dom=new DOMDocument();
$xml='images.xml';
    $dom->load($xml);
    $xp = new DomXPath($dom);
$i = 0;
    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('photo') as $item) {
        $cdata=$dom->createCDATASection('<head>test'.($i+1).'</head><body></body>');
        $item->appendChild($cdata);
$i ++;
    }
    $dom->save($xml);
```

Comment: thank u it work, just anther thing , if i want edit CDATA value from test1 to anther value it there  edirCDATASection or what? thank u  again